# Delete the rows of matrix with Inf

Tags: r, matrix, nan, cbind

I have three lists with Inf as a numeric and "NaN" as a character variable.

```
    v1<-list(1,Inf,3,4,5,6,"NaN")
    v2<-list(1,"NaN",3,4,5,6,5)
    v3<-list(1,2,3,4,5,6,"NaN")
```

for the moment I can make a matrix with cbind, but the desired result is the code B).

A) What I got:

```
matrix<-cbind(v1,v2,v3)
     v1    v2    v3   
[1,] 1     1     1    
[2,] Inf  "NaN"  2    
[3,] 3     3     3    
[4,] 4     4     4    
[5,] 5   Inf     5    
[6,] 6     6     6    
[7,]"NaN"  7   "NaN"
```

B) I want to get:

```
     v1    v2    v3   
[1,] 1     1     1      
[2,] 3     3     3    
[3,] 4     4     4       
[4,] 6     6     6
```

Context:
I wanted to export into a .txt file some results located in 3 lists, the easy for me was to use cbind to get a matrix and use

```
write.table(matrix, file="mymatrix.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: `matrix[apply(matrix,1, function(x) all(is.finite(x))),]`

Comment: Of course the topic is related but it is not duplicated, obviously the application and case is really different... there is anything new but the way to mix existing functions to get a result is new in this website, so thank you for your efforts to report the question but all you were totally wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of suggestions regarding the problem.

1) It is better not to name a `matrix` object as `matrix`.

2) `NaN`  or `NA` have a special meaning and are not character strings.  By using quotes `"NaN"`, it becomes difficult to apply the custom functions `is.nan/is.na` to do any manipulations.  So, we have to resort to `==/!=`

3) It is not clear why the individual `list` are `cbind`ed to a `matrix`.

---

Based on the input data, we can loop through the columns of 'matrix' with `apply`, then loop through each of the `list` elements, check whether we have a finite element and is not a "NaN", get the `rowSums`, negate (`!` - converts the 0 elements to TRUE i.e. all the elements in the row are finite and all other values to FALSE).  Use the logical index to subset the rows.

```
 matrix[!rowSums(apply(matrix, 2, FUN = function(x) 
         sapply(x, function(y) !(is.finite(y) & y !="NaN")))),]
 #    v1 v2 v3
 #[1,] 1  1  1 
 #[2,] 3  3  3 
 #[3,] 4  4  4 
 #[4,] 6  6  6
```